# Does it mean memory leaks in node.js?

Tags: node.js, memory, memory-leaks, amazon-ec2, buffer

I am using node.js 0.10.18 (on Amazon EC2) as our ios game http server.

I use `process.memoryUsage()` to print memory usage.
I find the memory usages of our nodes are abnormal.

After running for two days:

node on `machine1`:

2014-10-13T02:35:04.782Z - vital: Process: heapTotal 119.70 MB heapUsed 84.62 MB rss 441.57 MB

node on `machine2`:

2014-10-13T02:36:01.057Z - vital: Process: heapTotal 744.72 MB heapUsed 108.19 MB rss 1045.53 MB

The results are:

1. Both the `heapUsage`s are very small, it has nothing to do with how long the node process runs.
2. The `heapTotal` on `machine2` is much larger than `heapUsed`, and it will never get small until I restart the process. But `heapTotal` on `machine1` seems normal.

   `machine1` is Amazon EC2 m3.xlarge, `machine2` is Amazon EC2 m3.medium. From Amazon CloudWatch I know that the performance of `machine2` is insufficient, sometimes the CPU usage of `machine2` goes to 100%. So does the abnormal `heapTotal` usage have something to do with the insufficiency of the hardware? The 100% cpu usage is not a result of our node processes because using the `node-usage` module I see that the cpu usage of our node process is never higher than 50%. I think the usage is stolen by the neighboring virtual machines (you know there is shared cpu time on Amazon EC2s).
3. I know that the buffer memory usage = `(rss - heapTotal)`. I find that the buffer memory usage on both machines will increase gradually. You see, both of the buffer memory usages are more than 300MB after running for two days.

My questions are:

1. Why `heapTotal` usage will not get released even if the `heapUsed` is very small? Is it a problem with node itself or else some bug of my own code? Is the only way to fix it to upgrade the hardware?
2. Why is the buffer usage increasing gradually? Does it mean there are memory leaks? Is it a problem with node itself or else some bug of my own code? Or just ignore it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From this post https://www.joyent.com/blog/walmart-node-js-memory-leak. I found that there was a memory leak bug in the version <= 0.10.21. And the bug was fixed in version 0.10.22

I upgraded node to the latest version 0.10.32 and also enhanced the hardware of machine2.

Both the two memory problems never appear again. The memory use of both will only increase by several MBs each day, and I think it is normal, because my node process will cache some player data.

So maybe the two problems are caused by the same reason and it has been fixed.